# How to specify type when using zeep

Tags: python, django, zeep

WSDL defines an element as follows

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="address" nillable="true" type="q146:Address"/>
```

My zeep request is as follows
`client.service.UpdateAddressDetails(address='sample@sample.com')`

But I am getting

> Missing element type
>   (UpdateAddressDetails.address.type)

From what i know i need to specify the type for this field. How can I do it,
I have come across this zeep [documentation](https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/datastructures.html#anytype-objects) but nothing clicked

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with uppercase 'A' in your address-parameter:

```
client.service.UpdateAddressDetails(Address='sample@sample.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`factory = client.type_factory('q146')
address = factory.Address(address='sample@sample.com')
client.service.UpdateAddressDetails(address=address)`